# Как прикинуться сетевым устройством (не localhost) в Питон

Tags: python, сокет

Задача простая: *общаться с другой программой, которая принимает и передает UDP-пакеты через различные сетевые устройства.*

Проблема в том, что в ней нельзя прописывать IP для работы, а она сама предлагает список из существующих устройств и 127.0.0.1 в этом списке естественно нет.

Можно ли как-то настроить питоновский socket, чтобы сторонняя прога увидела его как интерфейс со своим IP ?

Или может другие методы в Питоне существуют ?

---

Вот так сделано на сях в одной рабочей проге

```
hpsdrSocket = new QUdpSocket(this);
hpsdrSocket->bind(1024, QUdpSocket::ShareAddress);
connect(hpsdrSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readHpsdrUDPData()));
```

Comment: Откуда она берет список? Вы может добавить правило маршрутизации и перенаправлять весь трафик на нужный вам адрес.

Comment: Видимо есть какой-то перечислитель интерфейсов, который выводит список существующих, и там кстати есть и виртуальные интерфейсы, которых нет физически на компе. Вот такое нужно сделать. Есть прога на сях, которая работает как нужно, могу посмотреть как там сделано.

Comment: а на какой ОС это все будет работать?

Comment: должно быть мультиплатформенным, но предпочтение - Винда.

Comment: Вот так сделано на сях в одной рабочей проге

hpsdrSocket = new QUdpSocket(this);
hpsdrSocket->bind(1024, QUdpSocket::ShareAddress);
connect(hpsdrSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readHpsdrUDPData()));

Comment: Параметр ShareAddress - это похоже ключевое слово, которое и делает всю магию

Comment: Если я в питоне создаю сокет с неким случайным IP , то выкидывает с ошибкой, а если использую IP физического интерфейса, то пакеты шлются только туда и сторонняя прога ничего не видит, так как слушает оттуда

Comment: Ну там Qt? Поставьте биндинг для питона и делайте то же самое.

Comment: что такое биндинг для питона ?

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=python%20qt%20binding

Comment: в Питоне есть socket модуль в стандартной библиотеке. В простейших случаях можно [`socketserver.py`  c `HOST=""` попробовать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#socketserver-udpserver-example) или [asyncio аналог](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#udp-echo-server-protocol) (чтобы на более низком уровне socket не писать)